# Carousel with nativescript-vue

Tags: carousel, nativescript, nativescript-vue

How can I create carousel with nativescript-vue? I can create couple of single components such as welcome1.vue, welcome2.vue with a button and animation, but I have no idea how can I add the dots to make it real carousel/introduction flow. I know there is an NS plugin for it, but I'm not sure how can I integrate it into vue project.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use https://github.com/manijak/nativescript-carousel

```
npm install nativescript-carousel
```

Then run 
`rm -rf platforms`

**Register the plugin in your app**

Open your `app.js` or `main.js` and add the following line at the top:
`Vue.registerElement('Carousel', () => require('nativescript-carousel').Carousel)`
`Vue.registerElement('CarouselItem', () => require('nativescript-carousel').CarouselItem)`

**Put this into your vue component:**
Remember to warp the `<Carousel>` inside a `<GridLayout>` if you're Android.

```
<Carousel height="100%" width="100%"
  pageChanged="myChangeEvent" pageTapped="mySelectedEvent"
  indicatorColor="#fff000" finite="true" bounce="false"
  showIndicator="true" verticalAlignment="top"
  android:indicatorAnimation="swap" color="white"
>
    <CarouselItem id="slide1" backgroundColor="#b3cde0" verticalAlignment="middle">
        <Label text="Slide 1" backgroundColor="#50000000" horizontalAlignment="center"/>
    </CarouselItem>
    <CarouselItem id="slide2" backgroundColor="#6497b1" verticalAlignment="middle">
        <Label text="Slide 2" backgroundColor="#50000000" horizontalAlignment="center"/>
    </CarouselItem>
    <CarouselItem id="slide3" backgroundColor="#005b96" verticalAlignment="middle">
        <Label text="Slide 3" backgroundColor="#50000000" horizontalAlignment="center"/>
    </CarouselItem>
    <CarouselItem id="slide4" backgroundColor="#03396c" verticalAlignment="middle">
        <Label text="Slide 4" backgroundColor="#50000000" horizontalAlignment="center"/>
    </CarouselItem>
</Carousel>
```

then run `tns run android --bundle`

Comment: Wow! Huge thank you for your detailed answer! Happy to have such a plugin for this! Thanks!

Comment: It works properly, however when I slide from 1 to 2, a white box appears on the top during the transition and disappears. How can I disable that? (Using ios) Thanks for your answer!

Comment: @arena I don't know. I only know how to use this plugin in Vue.js. You can explore more detail in this plugin.

Comment: Thanks for your note: Remember to warp the <Carousel> inside a <GridLayout> if you're Android.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try [nativescript-pager](https://github.com/triniwiz/nativescript-pager), it has official support for Vue and got a [demo](https://github.com/triniwiz/nativescript-pager/tree/master/demo-vue) app too.

Comment: Really appreciate your comment, I will check this out!